# Set immutableID for all users to UPN

Tags: powershell, office365, upn

I need to set the immutable ID of all users to their UPN. I have a two line powershell script to do it for a single user. Essentially i want to make this recursive and to run for every user in the tenant. I'm newish to powershell with office 365. I'm not sure how to make this happen.

```
get-msoluser -UserPrincipalName "someuser@somedomain.onmicrosoft.com" | foreach {$_.UserPrincipalName} | Set-Variable UPN1
set-msoluser -UserPrincipalName "someuser@somedomain.onmicrosoft.com" -immutableID “$UPN1”
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what isn't working?

Comment: The main issue I have is that the only tenant I can test on is federated and if I go testing things that don't work and change all ImmutableID's to something other than the UPN it already is, then I break it for all users.

Answer (score 0):

You already had the work in your two lines, just modified to get all MSOLUsers and process each user.  This could take a while if you have lots of users.  You may want to look into filters for Get-MSOLUser before you run something like this.

```
get-msoluser -All | ForEach-Object {
    set-msoluser -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName -immutableID $_.UserPrincipalName
}
```

I'm not 100% sure about the curly quotes for you immutableID in your example `“$UPN1”`.  Did this even need to be quoted?

Comment: I had read that if you don't quote a variable there that it can cause problems. Thank you so much for this code. I was having issues using $_.UserPricipalName to set the immutableID. When i used that all i would get is the @domain.onmicrosoft.com part